# Percentage ReCalculation when a new category is added

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm

I have a problem right now where I have a list of percentages that add to 100%, that i display in my swift app.

Now I allow the user to add additional items within the list and i have to recalculate the new list so it equalizes to 100% again and I am not too sure which is the best way to do this.

Please note I have made up the numbers so feel free to correct any of these numbers.

```
Example (original):
------------------------------------
Rent Share: 50%;
Entertainment Expenditure: 40%;
Shopping : 10%;

Total: 100%
-------------------------------------

Example (user estimates an out of pocket expense say Health as 2 % ):
-------------------------------------
Rent Share: X;
Entertainment Expenditure: Y;
Shopping : Z;
Health - 2 % 
Total: 100%; (thats is X+Y+Z + 2 % = 100%)
-------------------------------------
How do i recalculate X, Y, Z values ?
```

Comment: Really it is up to you to decide. You could take the overage from each item equally (so in your example, take .666% from the three existing entries. Personally, I would just let the total exceed 100% and show it in red and/or with a warning message that the user needs to adjust their amounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, X+Y+Z shall be equal to 100-2=98%, but used to be 100. So, multiply them by 98/100

X = 50*98/100 = 49
Y = 40*98/100 = 39.2
Z = 10*98/100 = 9.8

Check X+Y+Z = 49 + 39.2 + 9.8 = 98

It will keep X/Y, X/Z and Y/Z ratios as well